# I am trying to retrieve the index of a value in array 1 and use that index to find the value to same index in array 2

Tags: c#, arrays, search

the below is the function where 2 arrays are being checked. Array 1 is searched for a value and the index of that value is used to retrieve the value at same index in array 2

```
public void raashiNumberRelations(string rashiValue, string[] raashiArray)
 {
   char[] MobileNum = textBox3.Text.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(MobileNum);
        int rv = Convert.ToInt32(rashiValue);
        string[] ra = raashiArray;
        int pos = 0;
        string combo1 = "";
        string combo2 = "";
        string combo3 = "";

        if (rv == 1)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 5);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 8);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 11);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 2)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 4);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 7);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 10);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 3)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 3);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 9);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 12);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 4)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 8);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 11);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 2);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 5)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 7);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 10);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 1);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 6)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 9);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 12);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 3);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 7)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 11);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 2);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 5);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 8)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 10);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 1);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 4);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 9)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 12);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 3);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 6);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 10)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 2);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 5);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 8);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 11)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 1);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 4);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 7);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }
        if (rv == 12)
        {
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 3);
            combo1 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 6);
            combo2 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 9);
            combo3 = MobileNum[0].ToString() + MobileNum[pos].ToString();
            rashiCombination(combo1, combo2, combo3);
        }


    }

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] mobileNum = new string[12];
        string[] raashiRow = new string[12];
        addSrNo();
        addMobileNumber();
        findCombinations();

        string zs = calcIndianRaashi(textBox1.Text);

        string[] data = new string[12];
        string[] CalVal = new string[12];
        int temp = 0;


        for (int i = ZodiacIndian; i <= 12; i++)
        {

            data[temp] = i.ToString();
            CalVal[temp] = GetCalculatedVal(i).ToString();
            temp++;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < ZodiacIndian; i++)
        {

            data[temp] = i.ToString();
            CalVal[temp] = GetCalculatedVal(i).ToString();
            temp++;

        }

        Array.Reverse(data);
        Array.Reverse(CalVal);

        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)                              

        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[j].Value = data[j];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)                               
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[j].Value = CalVal[j];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
        {
            mobileNum[i] = c[i].ToString();
        }

        raashiRow = data;
        raashiNumberRelations(data[11], raashiRow);
        displayGrahaEffects(mobileNum);

    }
```

the output is giving an error array out of bounds as the value for pos is always staying -1 for some reason

Comment: This is certainly way too much code to demonstrate the problem. Strip it down to a minimal working example (expected 7 line of code)

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Set Breakpoints? step through your code? check array lengths? compared variable values against expected values? It will take you 2 minutes to find all your errors.

Comment: Too much duplicated code. Refactor by extracting private member functions.

Comment: i tried debugger but the value of pos stays -1

Comment: `pos`is initialized to `0` it becomes `-1` because `Array.IndexOf()` fails to find the item you're looking for.

Comment: `for (int i = ZodiacIndian; i <= 12; i++)` The variable (*ZodiacIndian*) is never initialized. Is it being set elsewhere, is it a mistake or ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of raashiArray value when you are calling pos = Array.IndexOf(ra, 12); Since your array is going to be of length 12 the last index it can have is 11. Put breakpoints and check the rest.

**EDIT**
OK how did I miss it. Array.IndexOf finds index of the string but you are entering it in int format hence it isnt able to find the specified string and hence its always 1. Specify numbers in "". Also make sure if double digits are stored as single string or not.
For eg

```
string[] temp = new string[]{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
int a = Array.IndexOf(temp, "3");
```

Comment: No problem bro. Just check if you array being passed is of specified length 12.

Comment: tried but it still wont stop giving me -1. Also i have tried using breakpoints and used test cases but I can't figure out why -1

Comment: hey even i found that... :D

Comment: Glad that you got it :D Most probably the downvotes was due to the size of your code most wont have bothered reading it :P. Here's an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The function `Array.IndexOf()` may return `-1` if the item is not found. You should **always** check for this condition and handle the error, probably printing the item you are searching for (and which is not present in the array).

Comment: I'll try to cut the code down to size a bit....

The array is always going to have the digits 1-12 in different places all the time. that is the reason i did not place a precautionary measure.

Comment: **Always** check return values. **Never** rely on assumptions.

Comment: i tried but it still wont stop giving me -1. Also i have tried using breakpoints and used test cases but I can't figure out why -1

Answer (score -1):

Hey I found the answer myself. This was a really silly solution. I was passing:

```
Array.IndexOf("My Array",value)
```

the function was thinking of value as an integer. My Array was a string array. I just redid it to:

```
Array.IndexOf(MyArray, "value") // Note it now thinks of value as string
```

And viola it works.